# What is the correct way of amplifying the output of an active filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, audio, active-filter

I have been trying hard to implement a narrow band pass filter using operational amplifiers.

Here is the circuit:

[image]

So far, I was able to get correct result in spice simulations, but when I put the hardware all together and power it up, I get a very faint signal at the output (PR3). By faint I mean, I connect a 15 W amplifier (TPA3110) to the circuit but the audio is at very low volume. It is like a 4 Ω, 5 W speaker driver given a signal direct from the headphone jack of your phone.

**EDIT**
Here is how the TPA module is connected:
[image]
Here is the transient curve @100 Hz:

[image]

Here is the AC sweep curve:

[image]

To be more aware, I probed the current in the simulation and it seems the input side (PR1) current (peak2peak) is around 1.3 mA, PR2 also shows 1.3 mA but, PR3 shows 1.4 pA.

Its seems the total power coming out is way too low.

Is there a way to amplify the power (current) at PR3?

How should I connect the TPA amplifier board correctly so that there is no anomaly in the global ground or power sources? Will that affect the signal quality and power?

Comment: Show your actual schematics, parts you used, and also the circuit design of your TPA3110 amp.

Comment: *TPA3110 amplifier* at what gain/input levels to GAIN0 and GAIN1? 20 dB isn't much. (What current did you expect at an output open according to the schematic diagram?)

Comment: V(1)/V(PR2) looks optimistic with the OpAmp supplied with +-8 V: 'scoped or simulated?

Comment: @Justme I am using the generic TPA module which is 15W + 15W for left & right. I am powering it with 16V from the same voltage source of the opamps.

Comment: @greybeard Honestly I have no idea of expected current, ideally I would require the current to be almost similar as the input side (maybe because it would give me required volume level). Also the values are simulation values, I have no means of measuring the ones on the hardware.

Comment: You need to show the TPA module schematic. I mean, it might be problematic directly interfacing it to your circuit and, please show how you connected the op-amps up in the filter.

Comment: So now it is a module. Yet no connections how you connected it and where. You might have it wrong.

Comment: @Justme I edited the question with the module connection , its rough though, but that's how I did that.

Comment: @Andyaka Unfortunately I am unable to find the schematic of the module.

Comment: You do realize you have shorted 
the negative supply, -8V, to GND?

Answer (score 1):

According to your updated diagram, you have shorted the negative supply to GND through the module.

The audio input GND is same GND as negative power supply terminal.

Comment: I checked, the input ground and power ground of the module are shorted. But if I connect module to the ground i.e. power the module only by V4, there is total silence on the speaker :-|

Answer (score 0):

I think that the filter components are scaled incorrectly.  By that I mean that they require too much current from the 2nd op-amp.

I would increase the values of resistors R4, R5, R9 by a factor of 10 or 100 and then reduce the values of capacitors C2 & C4 by the same scale factor.

You can also get much more gain from the circuit by increasing the value of R2 in the first stage.

Comment: I tried by choosing the factor of 10, the components were available to me. But still there is no significant change at the output. However, the simulation shows about 3.1pA now instead of 1.4pA. Can you explain me how that would work ? Wont it induce higher input impedance for the seconds opamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter resistors are overloading the opamp (reducing its output level) and are causing the filter capacitors to be electrolytic with bad tolerance. Change the 330 ohms to 33k, change the 100 ohms to 10k and change the 10uF to 100nF 5% film type.

The datasheet of the TPA3110 shows an output of 3.5W into 8 ohms at low distortion when the supply is only plus and minus 8V.

The gain of the preamp opamp, the active filter and the TDA3110 should be plenty.
Why only frequencies near 100Hz?
[image: active filter]

Comment: I tried with 3.3k and 1uF parts as mentioned by Dwayne . There was no significant change though. The values you mentioned, I simulated them which shows the same results so far. Ill have to buy these components to put implement the circuit. Hoping for the best when I do it!

Answer (score 0):

The TPA3110 is not designed to use a positive and negative supply. It uses only a positive supply and 0V ground. Maybe the people who made your amplifier board did not know the the input ground must be at the 0V ground voltage and not at half the total supply voltage.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you have actually the module connected correctly, and that above comments to the contrary are wrong, unless perhaps you changed your drawing. I looked at your modules documentation, You have the bottom VCC and GND connected correctly. At the inputs on the left side  the left input is open, the center ground connected to audio common, and are driving the right channel. Besides the inputs are capacitor coupled and can't cause a DC short. One thing to be aware is that the outputs are not referenced to ground. You can't connect ground referenced test equipment like an oscilloscope up. You mention using a speaker, which is of course, OK.

In your question you are confusing what the amplifiers are doing. Audio amplifiers that drive speakers are called "power amplifiers" and indeed they do put out more audio power than is inputted to them. However power transfer in the intermediate stages are just about never of a concern because almost always the input resistance (or impedance if you must) of the driven stage is several orders of magnitude bigger than the output resistance of the driver. This is especially true when op amp stages are being used. Indeed the data sheet for the TPA3110 shows that the input impedance is at least 9000 Ohms. The output impedance of your filter should be less than an Ohm, I believe. So the TPA3110 can be thought of as a voltage amplifier that can drive small resistances to a fairly large voltage, generating as much as 15 Watts with a 24 volt supply. You don't mention what voltage you are driving the filter with, or what frequency. As your filter is narrow, and sometimes real circuits don't work the same as modeled circuits did you try to change the frequency to see if you were at the peak response?

The TPA3110 can be set for various gains between 20 and 36 dB, I'm going to assume the builders of your board tried for 30 dB which is a voltage gain of 31. If you want to drive your 4 Ohm speaker with 100 mW which is .632 VMS or about 1.8 V P-P than you need about 57 mV (.057) at the input of the module, and as your simulation shows the filter has a gain of 0.4 about 144 mV at the input to your filter. Do you know what that voltage level is?

The values in your filter seem odd, but I assume the simulation shows that they should work. I would normally use smaller caps and bigger resistors as previously mentioned. You discuss input currents, one of which is in the pA range. Don't look at the currents into the pins of the opamps, they will be small, look at the currents in the resistors, and capacitors if you must. But the only thing you really need to know is the voltage into the TPA3110. If you have a DVM that can measure AC millivolts use it.

Comment: Not true. The pin labeled "GND" on audio input is connected by the PCB to power supply terminal labeled with "-". Therefore the module PCB shorts the audio common to negative supply, and thus the connections cannot be correct like you claim.

Comment: Why did the amplifier module manufacturer wrongly label the Power Ground connection "-" when the TPA3110 power amplifier IC does not use a negative supply? With an 8VDC and Ground supply, the output power into an 8 ohms speaker is 2.8W at maximum level before clipping.

Comment: I stand corrected, indeed the, TPA3110 module power  is incorrectly connected as others pointed out, I was fooled by the double use of black, and too terse a look, I guess.